Why are there so few signatories of the European Convention on State Immunity?
The 1972 European Convention on State Immunity, which "sets out the circumstances under which a signatory may not claim immunity before a foreign court", only has minority of (8) European countries signing up to it: Austria, Belgium, Cyprus, Germany, Luxembourg, Netherlands, Switzerland, and the UK.
What did the other European countries, that didn't join the Convention, say about why they didn't do so or what would they gain by not signing it?

Could you add a sentence or two on what this convention is about, so this doesn't become a link-only question.

I don't think this question can be answered without a whole lot of mind-reading, so vote to close. But I'll point out that this convention seems to have implications for state sovereignty i.e. creating circumstances in which states are obliged to submit to foreign courts. I can see that being a serious concern for a lot of states, for innumerable reasons.

@TedWrigley: why? Countries will usually state their positions on such matters. Especially since this was a treaty advanced through the Council of Europe.

Reformulated the question in the body somewhat to ask less open ended and more factual.

Countries will state their positions when it's advantageous to do so. I'm sure that if a country had a principled objection they'd have put it in writing.  But if a state was worried that this convention could be used to force it to (say) pay its debts or change its internal policies (think about the disputes between the EU and Greece during Greece's debt crisis), it probably wouldn't advertise that fact.

What's in it for them, besides giving up some rights?  As Ted says.   Plus, if few have joined, there is little pressure on those holding out joining a 52 yr old convention not even warranting a wiki article.  But they may still not want to unnecessarily publicize a stand that might strike some as dodgy (the US gets a fair bit of flak for its position vis a vis the ICJ for example).

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica: well, if the [European] countries not signing it are known to apply the principle of "absolute immunity" [in such matters], then that would be an answer, wouldn't it? There are dozen and dozens of papers about this, e.g. https://rm.coe.int/final-publication-state-immunity-under-international-law-and-current-c/16807724e9 I find it hard to believe it would require just rank speculation to answer this Q. (Not that either you or Ted shy from that in answers sometimes.)

@TedWrigley: Here's e.g. China explaining a change in their position (but also has a quote explaining their older position) https://npcobserver.com/2023/09/china-foreign-state-immunity-law/ (That's discussed relative to the UN draft rather than the European Convention.)

Well, I did upvote, but now this "rank speculation" hurt my feelings.  In 1972 8 was probably about half the membership in any case.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Council_of_Europe#Member_states_and_observers  Point is:  it's very old stuff, and I for one find Google has been worse and worse for a while, esp on old pages.  On the other hand, Bing has a broken UI when it comes to setting date limits.  Doubt we'll get an answer.

This question and the lack of answers seems to highlight the limits of knowledge, especially about true causes. Even if we would know what states that didn't sign that convention said about why they didn't sign it, if they said anything, we don't know if they maybe lied or omitted something, there could be different causes. And about possible advantages we can only speculate. In the end, it's always just a judgement call. Here, we want to limit the extent of speculation. All why questions will suffer from the same problem.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution: TBH France kinda said why they didn't. See my other Q on Germany. I suspect a number of other (mostly Eastern) European countries that signed the UN convention but not this one might hold a similar position [to France's], but I'll need to find more confirmation before putting it as an answer. Also, the UN convention didn't exist even as a draft until the 1990s or so, so the motivation[s] before then were probably a little different.
